# Prove that every subspace of $V$ of dimension $n - 1$ is orthogonal to some vector in V using the dimension theorem

Tags: linear-algebra, vector-spaces

Suppose that $W$ is a subspace of $V = F^n$ over some arbitrary field $F$. $dim(W) = n - 1$.

Using the dimension theorem, show that there exists $(a_1, a_2, \dots, a_n) \in F^n$ such that
$$W = \{(c_1, c_2, \dots, c_n) \in F^n : a_1c_1 + \dots + a_nc_n = 0\} $$

Edit:
I was able to prove that $W$ is a subset of the set on the right, but have no idea how to prove the other inclusion.

Also I should not have used orthogonal in the title, since this exercise appeared before othogonality is defined. So is there any way of doing this without using orthogonality?

Comment: Hint: Find some vector not in $W$, and subtract from it its orthogonal projection to $W$. That should give you $(a_1,a_2,\ldots,a_n)$. From there, show that $W$ is a subset of the right hand side, that the RHS is a linear substace, and that the right hand side does not contain $(a_1,a_2,\ldots,a_n)$. These facts should be enough.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let $w_1,\dots,w_{n-1}$ be a basis of $W,$ check the null space of the linear map from $V$ to $W$ defined by
$$x \mapsto (x \cdot w_1,\dots,x \cdot w_{n-1}).$$
I'm not sure what you mean in the edit, but if I interpreted it right, the problem should be solved by considering the linear map $x \mapsto x \cdot a$ for any $a$ that is orthogonal to all of $W.$

Comment: I used this linear map and was able to show that W is a subset of the set on the right, but I am not sure how to proceed from there and prove the other inclusion. So could you give me some hints?

Comment: The null space of $x \mapsto x \cdot a$ has  dimension at most $n-1$ for any nonzero $a.$

Comment: Thank you very much. That hint was really helpful